# How to create a button that spawns a movable image? iOS 5

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5

I would like to create a button in my UIView that when touched spawns another button under the finger which immediately starts to follow the finger.

I have seen a tutorial here that deals with button following finger, but i can not figure out how to make this button follow finger WITHOUT user tapping it after creation.

Using iOS 5.1 SDK with XCode 4.3.2

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add target/action pairs to a button for various control events: to make something immediately start following your finger, you probably want `UIControlEventTouchDown`.

Hook up your first button to call a method on your view controller for that control state. In that action method, create your new button, and shove it in a property on your view controller so that you can refer to it later. Also set a BOOL property on your view controller that's called something like `shouldTrackButton`.

To make the new button follow your finger, I guess the easiest way is a pan gesture recogniser on the superview. Set that up to call a method on your view controller. In that method, if the gesture recogniser's state is `UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged`, call `translationInView:` on the gesture recogniser, passing in the view controller's view (i.e. the superview of the buttons). Now, if and only if `shouldTrackButton` is `YES`, take the frame of the original button, translate it by that amount (using `CGRectApplyAffineTransform` and `CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation`), and set the new button's frame to the result.

Finally, in the same method, if the gesture recogniser's state is `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded`, set `shouldTrackButton` to `NO`.

Comment: That's a bit too dirty i think, but thanks :) I have solved the problem by a trick - i just let the object itself be dragged and create a 'replacement' in the place where dragging started.